# YamlDotNet can not find property

Tags: c#, yamldotnet

I am trying to create a simple model for parsing a yaml file to my domain object using [YamlDotNet](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/tree/5d9948940a8cdcb8a1cf2cf77c5b89bf360e8409). The caveat is, that I want the domain model to be readonly, so I'm attempting to solve this through inheritance and internal setters.

For some reason though, the library throws an exception stating:

> Property '﻿HtmlTemplate' not found on type
>   'ConsoleApplication1.Repositories.YamlTemplateRepository+DeserializeableTemplate'.

I am using an alias, but even scratching that, and using a test class with the right property names does not set it right.

What am I doing wrong? Have I misunderstood how the library should be used?

The code that calls YamlDotNet looks like this:

```
deserializer.Deserialize<DeserializeableTemplate>(yamlContents);
```

and the class I'm deserializing looks like this:

```
private class DeserializeableTemplate : Template
{
  [YamlMember(Alias = "HtmlTemplate")]
  public string HtmlTemplateWrapper
  {
    get { return HtmlTemplate; }
    set { HtmlTemplate = value; }
  }

  // A few more properties...
}
```

and the class I am inheriting:

```
public class Template
{
  public string HtmlTemplate { get; internal set; }
  // A few more properties...
}
```

([Small console test application with the same error can be found here](https://github.com/JohnyWS/Yaml-mapper-testproject/blob/master/ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1/Repositories/YamlTemplateRepository.cs))

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I had a similar issue, which was solved by changing the access modifier of the inherited property setter to `protected`. I'm guessing the `internal` modifier used here is playing tricks on the deserialization. This might be an unwanted solution for this problem regarding making the model truly readonly, but I wanted to share my solution for future troubleshooters.

Comment: Ah that's it! My problem was that the properties were readonly.

Comment: I have the same problem but everything is public

Comment: My issues appears to be that despite using the Alias, its not finding the field because of mixed naming conventions. Some fields are using camelCase others are using hyphen-case, and simply using the alias doesn't solve it. Setting `ApplyNamingConventions = false` as well as the alias on the specific fields that violate the naming convention allows it to find the field.